# ViewController in separate storyboard using RBStoryboardLink has extra 20px black status bar when hide navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c

I tried using RBStoryboardLink to separate storyboard in my project, and in one of the storyboard, I have an initial view controller which is embedded in navigation controller,and I use `[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];` to hide navigation bar. 
However it will introduce a 20px black area in status bar as below
[image]

I have tried options such as uncheck `extend edges under top bars` or uncheck `adjust scroll view insets` but nothing works so far.

anyone has any clue how to resolve this issue? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to find a solution for my case.
The key is `_needsTopLayoutGuide`
I customised another called RBStoryboardNoNavLink and set `_needsTopLayoutGuide` to NO in that class, and if the storyboard link is a tab child view controller and do not want navigation bar (or do not embed in navigation controller even), can just rename that class to `RBStoryboardNoNavLink` and it works perfectly for my case.